# Regular expression, get an array from captured group Java

Tags: java, regex

I have some text that occurs in a particular format as shown below
Each line starts with a + followed by a space and some text
It then has a bunch of lines stuck together that start with a minus sign or @ or % or * and space and some text following it. I would like to capture each block separately from below using Regular expressions.

```
+ you rock
- I rock and rule.

+ you rule
- I rock and rule.
- That is a perfect artificial entity.

+ you made a mistake
- That is impossible. I never make mistakes.
- I guess so, something must have gone wrong.
```

Output

**Block 1**
    + you rock
    - I rock and rule.

**Block 2**
    + you rule
    - I rock and rule.
    - That is a perfect artificial entity.

This is my current regular expression

```
(^\+.*$)(?:\r?\n)(?:(^[-%@\*].*$)(?:\r?\n)?)+
```

In the above expression, Group 1 = (^+.*$) that captures the statement following a +, group 2 = (^[-%@*].*$) that captures the second part but notice that there may be more than one statement which has a - at the start.

When I run a while loop in Java code

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(contents);
while (matcher.find()) {
    // This gives me the item following +
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    // This ONLY gives me the last item following -, how do I get all
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

How do I get all the statements that have a minus sign in front of them as an array?

Comment: Basically, you can't do it.  You'll need `split` or a loop.  But I want to question your premise: _Why is it important to solve this with a regular expression?_  What's wrong with other types of solutions?  Are they somehow uncool?  I've been trying to understand this for years--why so many programmers seem to assume that they need to find the magical regex to solve something.  Second question: Do you think that code like `(^\+.*$)(?:\r?\n)(?:(^[-%@\*].*$)(?:\r?\n)?)+` makes a program more or less readable?

Comment: nice point but honestly i am not aware of what other solutions may work for this problem, i have a file with around 300000 lines of text in this format and would like to parse them to blocks and extract and process information from them

Comment: btw how can I split or loop the second part which has a - sign

Comment: Hint: since Java 8 we have `\R` which represents line separators (including `\r\n` so you can use it instead of `\r?\n`). Anyway, why do you want to have these parts in array? What are you trying to achieve? Maybe reading this text line-by-line, while checking if you found empty line would be easier?

Comment: "Not aware of other solutions"?  Can't you just read one line at a time and use `charAt()` or `startsWith()` to see if the first character is `+` or `-`?

Comment: I would like to extract each block as an object store the item with a + under one variable and store the items with a minus under an array and sort all the items on the basis of + with a custom comparator

Comment: The file format is not that simple, it is a syntax oriented file almost like a programming language, has comments, variables and so on, but unlike programming languages, it has only 4 types of constructs, one of them is called a rule that starts with a + and has a bunch of - or @ or % or * following it, I am trying to extract all rules from a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this regexp `^\+[^+]*` with `m` and `g` modifiers gives you needed result
https://regex101.com/r/bH1aQ9/1

On your test data result will be 3 groups start with `+` character.

The solution idea is to treat all you lines like one big line and split it on groups is started with `+` and haven't `+` inside them.

**Update**

To take into account @Pshemo note about possible `+` characters inside lines

Regexp `^\+.*?(^$|\Z)` with with `s`, `m` and `g` modifiers
https://regex101.com/r/bH1aQ9/1

Comment: WHOA! that took 12 steps for 3 matches, i was at 17 steps per match, that was badass, I know this [] means pick an item from that box, but can you please explain what [^+]* means, from what I read it says pick all plus signs optionally that are at the beginning

Comment: @PirateApp `[^+]*` means 0 or more characters in brackets (it defines `*` postfix) and `^+` inside the brackets means any character but not (`^`) plus.

Comment: thank you very much, i got confused with the begin ^ :) and mistook it for negation. your solution works badass, i wish i could give a 100 more upvotes

Comment: @PirateApp thx! But be careful with regexps http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247

Comment: @PirateApp Just be aware that this solution will not accept any `+` inside your group (except first one). So for instance `+ I like + operator` will stop at `+ I like `.

Comment: @Pshemo you are right, but in source data there was not such corner case. I would update the task conditions with this note.

Comment: @Pshemo added the second solution bases on your note

Comment: how to get this to work in Java. I tried setting Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.DOT_ALL, it doesnt generate any output

Comment: String regex = "^\\+.*?(^$|\\Z)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex,Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(contents);
has no output whatsoever

Comment: This works!
String regex = "(^\\+[\\s\\S]*)?(^$|\\Z)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE); in Java